# switch user not working in Xubuntu 14.04

Tags: xubuntu, login, xscreensaver

When I click the switch user in the Actions Buttons in my panel, I get this message:

```
GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.gnome.DisplayManager was not provided by any .service files
```

I get the same message if I lock the screen and then select New Login option (I'm using xscreensaver).

If I type `dm-tool switch-to-greeter` in terminal I get into the login screen and can enter with a new user but that is not an elegant method. I want the actual buttons to work!

The other posts on this topic are either unresolved or do not work for me. Any advice?

EDIT: this seems to be a bug. I filled a new bug [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfswitch-plugin/+bug/1320560) and there is a similar bug reported [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfswitch-plugin/+bug/1320560).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is fixed in package `whisker-menu` but still not in package `xfce4-panel`. It appears that 'actions' is hardcoded to execute `gdmflexiserver` which only works if `gdm` is used instead of `lightdm`, which in turn is the xubuntu default.

You have, as always, several options:

- Drop the actions item or disable user switch there and enable and use it in whisker-menu
- Switch to gdm (apparently already installed)
- Create a deviation from `/usr/bin/gdmflexiserver` to a script that calls `dm-tool switch-to-greeter`, like whisker-menu already does
- Recreate 'actions' with a custom dropdown launcher duplicating all necessary commands

If I remember correctly, previous versions of lightdm would provide a gdmflexiserver compatibility hack that is no longer around.

Comment: Thanks, the first solution worked. I tried the second one (although I had to install gdm) but it tripled booting time, plus it looked much uglier so I discarded it. The fact that xfce4-panel is not fixed, does it mean I should report a bug? (I'm rather new into linux).

Comment: You can submit xubuntu bugs here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/xfce4-panel/+bugs. A cursory check reveals that this bug is not yet reported.

Comment: I decided to switch to gdm to fix this for my situation because I need to be able to lock my screen before another user uses the same computer, so they wouldn't be able to access the whisker-menu.

Comment: The workaround with /usr/bin/gdmflexiserver to become a script that calls "dm-tool switch-to-greeter" worked great for me (with XUbuntu 16.04)